# How do I extract columns directly from a trigger's procedure code in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have triggers that update a table's respective history table with the old column value when a record is updated or deleted. This is an example of a trigger that updates the `contact_history` table if the main `contact` table is updated:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.contact_history_insert()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
          IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            INSERT INTO public.contact_history
              (dml_type, hard_deleted_on, first_name, last_name, middle_name)
            VALUES 
              ('D', now(), OLD.first_name OLD.last_name, OLD.middle_name)
            RETURN OLD;
          ELSEIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            INSERT INTO public.contact_history
              (dml_type, first_name, last_name, middle_name)
            VALUES
              ('U', OLD.first_name OLD.last_name, OLD.middle_name);
            NEW.modified_on = now();
            RETURN NEW;
          END IF;
        END;
```

I am trying to write a query that allows me to extract the columns from the trigger's procedure code. Now, I realize that I can query the table `pg_attribute` to get a trigger's information using this query:

```
SELECT  att_name
FROM pg_attribute
WHERE attrelid = (SELECT tgrelid FROM pg_trigger WHERE tgname = 'contact_history_trigger')
AND attnum > 0;
```

However, this does not give me the result I'm looking for. This gives the result of the columns that will be updated, but not the result of the actual columns used in the procedural code written in the trigger. For example, if I add a new column to the `contact` table without updating the contact trigger, it will automatically update the `attname` in `pg_attribute`. This is NOT identical to the actual columns that were written in the trigger code. So, I'm trying to write a query that will return the results of the columns listed in the trigger code. I realize that this probably includes using a regex expression to extract the data from the INSERT INTO statements. I would also like to split the data into individual variables and place them into a new array variable:

```
--Extract this data from the trigger code
(dml_type, hard_deleted_on, first_name, last_name, middle_name)
('D', now(), OLD.first_name, OLD.last_name, OLD.middle_namee)
(dml_type, first_name, last_name, middle_name)
('U', OLD.first_name OLD.last_name, OLD.middle_name)

---Expected output
vars_1 = [first_name, last_name, middle_name]
vars_2 = [OLD.first_name, OLD.last_name, OLD.middle_name] -- It would be a plus if it didn't extract the 'OLD' prefix
vars_3 = [first_name, last_name, middle_name]
vars_4 = [OLD.first_name, OLD.last_name, OLD.middle_name]
```

This does seem overly complicated but I haven't found an easier way of just retrieving the data by just calling a system table such as `pg_attribute` or `information_schema.triggers` without it being the wrong information that I am looking for.

I do know this query returns the actual procedural code for the trigger:

```
SELECT prosrc FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'contact_history_insert';
```

Comment: Can you tell us what it is that you want to achieve with this code? I have this nagging feeling that there may be a much cleaner solution to your real problem.

Comment: It is quite complicated to write a generic trigger function like that. Complicated functions tend to be slower. You might be better off writing a trigger function for each table. You could generate the function code by querying the metadata.

Comment: I am trying to make sure that the  columns in my triggers  match their respective tables. There may be cases where a trigger is missing a column or maybe a column name is spelled incorrectly. This would cause the old data value to not be inserted in the history table. I successfully created a function that works properly in programmatically checking that the tables’ columns match the triggers’ columns only to find out that I was using the wrong query from the pg_attribute system table (as mentioned above) to query the triggers columns. It gave me the table columns and not the trigger columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same order of columns in the tables, and the additional fields in the history table are only at the end of the table, you can write your query like this.

```
CREATE TABLE contact (
    first_name varchar NULL,
    last_name varchar NULL,
    middle_name varchar NULL
);

CREATE TABLE contact_history (
    first_name varchar NULL,
    last_name varchar NULL,
    middle_name varchar NULL,
    hard_deleted_on timestamp NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test2.contact_history_insert()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO contact_history
    select new.*, now();
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$
;

create trigger contact_insert_trigger 
after insert
    on
    test2.contact for each row execute function test2.contact_history_insert();
```

This is working.
Second way you can use dynamic query inside the trigger and you can get table columns names using `information_schema`